# What does overflow:table do?

Tags: css

What does `overflow: table` means or does for a div? How is different from `overflow: auto`?

```css
div#layout { overflow: table; }
```

Comment: do u mean `display:table` ??

Comment: @SaurabhLP : No actually meant overflow:table, which I thought could be something like display:table, but did not find any authentic doc regarding this. Anyways now I got it, its not a valid value for overflow property. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is [no such value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow).  It's probably the same as `overflow: auto;` because it's being ignored as an invalid value.

As a test, try changing it to `overflow: bananas;` and see if it has the same effect.

Comment: :D +1 for the suggestion.

Comment: haha...overflow:bananas..:D

Comment: This is funny :) I got this in legacy code. And, did a exhaustive search to find this out, without any luck. Anyways..Thanks for the clarification. :)

Answer (score 1):

The **overflow** property specifies what happens if content overflows an element's box.

Different overflow properties are

**visible**-->  The overflow is not clipped. It renders outside the element's box. This is default

**hidden**-->   The overflow is clipped, and the rest of the content will be invisible

**scroll**-->   The overflow is clipped, but a scroll-bar is added to see the rest of the content

**auto**--> If overflow is clipped, a scroll-bar should be added to see the rest of the content

**inherit**-->  Specifies that the value of the overflow property should be inherited from the parent element

Thanks
AB